# How to properly pass input to a dynamic child views

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement a (navigation) tabs system, allowing to switch between several views of the same data (stored/changed by the parent view).

I am using a @ViewChild to populate a `<template>` tag, but either I am passing data or instantiating things the wrong way, or this is simply not possible: I have 2 problems:

- I cannot directly instantiate the child component with its input data, and have to execute that in a setTimeout()
- The child component does not get updated when the variable passed as @Input changes

This is illustrated on the following [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/bSZtiRoPyYwoeNnfx1P2?p=preview):
Extract:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div style="padding: 10px">

      Count is {{count}}
      <button (click)="increase()">increase</button>

    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let v of views" (click)="selectView(v)">{{v[0]}}</li>
    </ul>

    <template #viewContainer></template>

    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  count = 1;

  @ViewChild('viewContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false })
  container: any;

  componentRef: ComponentRef<any>|null = null;

  views = [
    ['One', ComponentOne],
    ['Two', ComponentTwo],
  ]

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }

  increase() {
    this.count += 1;
  }

  selectView(v: any) {
    this.container.clear();
    const factory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(v[1]);
    this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
    (<ComponentRef<any>>this.componentRef).instance.count = this.count;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // This causes ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
    //this.selectView(this.views[1]);
    // This works
    setTimeout(()=> {this.selectView(this.views[1]);} );
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'comp-one',
  template: `
      Component 1: Count is {{count}}
  `,
})
export class ComponentOne {
  @Input count: any;
}
```

Is there a way I can improve things ?

Comment: This looks fine to me.

Comment: Sorry I sent the wrong plunkr link I think. It should be fixed now.

Comment: The "I cannot directly instantiate the child component with its input data, and have to execute that in a setTimeout()" seems to be a legit work around see: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005#issuecomment-177231549

Comment: `allowing to switch between several views of the same data (stored/changed by the parent view)` - Regarding this, why not create a service that stores the data and also returns an observable. All dynamically generated child views will subscribe to this observable onInit and retrieve latest data stored and also subsequent updated (.next()) data?

Comment: I'd like to avoid something as global as a service, as this should just be about the interactions between the parent and the children components (imagine that in theory there could be several instances of the parent at a time). Even having to declare the children components in entryComponents was a bit much, to my taste :) (but does not prevent several instances I suppose).